# Why are the numbers 1-5 output with "state" and 11111 with "my"? And what does "state" do in general?

Tags: perl

Why are the numbers 12345 output with "state" and 11111 with "my"?

```
sub Counter{
    
    state $i= 0;
    $i++;
    print "$i\n";
}

for (1..5){
    Counter();
}
```

Comment: `my` variables are scoped to the code block, they initialize again every time the block runs. `state` variables have the same scope, as they are not globals, but they are only initialized the first time, and the value persists between each run.

Answer (score 5):

From [the docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state):

> state declares a lexically scoped variable, just like my. However, those variables will **never be reinitialized**, contrary to lexical variables that are reinitialized each time their enclosing block is entered.

Comment: perl has excellent documentation and it comes installed with perl itself, running `perldoc -f state` in the command line gives the above answer. perldoc should be the first place anyone looks for answers, before going to SO